# SequenceMatcher unable to distinguish between 'replace' and 'insert'

Tags: python, python-3.x, opcode, difflib, sequencematcher

**First example:**

```
one = ['billy', 'sally', 'gd', 'kk', 'btb']
two = ['billy', 'sally', 'hh', 'kk', 'ff', 'btb']
opcodes1 = SequenceMatcher(None, one, two).get_opcodes()
opcodes2 = SequenceMatcher(None, two, one).get_opcodes()
```

**correctly** returns the `insert` **ff**:

```
[('equal', 0, 5, 0, 5), ('replace', 5, 6, 5, 6), ('equal', 6, 9, 6, 9), ('insert', 9, 9, 9, 11), ('equal', 9, 10, 11, 12)]
[('equal', 0, 5, 0, 5), ('replace', 5, 6, 5, 6), ('equal', 6, 9, 6, 9), ('delete', 9, 11, 9, 9), ('equal', 11, 12, 9, 10)]
```

Now, I would like `get_opcodes()` to find a `'insert'` which is next to a `'replace'` ... but it is unable.

**Second example:**

```
one = ['billy', 'sally', 'gd', 'kk', 'btb']
two = ['billy', 'sally', 'hh', 'kk1', 'ff', 'btb']
opcodes1 = SequenceMatcher(None, one, two).get_opcodes()
opcodes2 = SequenceMatcher(None, two, one).get_opcodes()
```

returns:

```
[('equal', 0, 2, 0, 2), ('replace', 2, 4, 2, 5), ('equal', 4, 5, 5, 6)]
[('equal', 0, 2, 0, 2), ('replace', 2, 5, 2, 4), ('equal', 5, 6, 4, 5)]
```

In this next example we **force the difference to be recognized**. I've added padding ... which amazingly is ignored ... this is so amazing because the `'kk'` in the **first example** is acting as padding, stopping the `'gd'` vs `'hh'` from being considered part of the `'ff'` insert

**Third example:**

```
one = ['///////', 'billy', '///////', 'sally', '///////', 'gd', '///////', 'kk', '///////', 'btb']
two = ['///////', 'billy', '///////', 'sally', '///////', 'hh', '///////', 'kk1', '///////', 'ff', '///////', 'btb']
opcodes1 = SequenceMatcher(None, one, two).get_opcodes()
opcodes2 = SequenceMatcher(None, two, one).get_opcodes()
```

returns:

```
[('equal', 0, 5, 0, 5), ('replace', 5, 6, 5, 6), ('equal', 6, 7, 6, 7), ('replace', 7, 8, 7, 10), ('equal', 8, 10, 10, 12)]
[('equal', 0, 5, 0, 5), ('replace', 5, 6, 5, 6), ('equal', 6, 7, 6, 7), ('replace', 7, 10, 7, 8), ('equal', 10, 12, 8, 10)]
```

Once again, failing to recognize the insert value **ff** when it is clearly there.

Comment: What do you mean by find an insert that is next to a replace?

Comment: `get_opcodes()` is able to identify if text is 'equal', 'replace', 'insert' or 'delete' ... when comparing two texts

Comment: Yes I am aware, so do you mean that the when you reverse the parameters, the corresponding one is a replace? It seems to me that the output in the first example is correct

Comment: no, the `insert` is not recognized at all. It is "merged" into the `replace` .... but it **is** recognized when a divider is used ... such as in example 1 where `'kk'` is dividing `'hh'` from `'ff'` ..... but if i add my own dividers ... it says ... nope!